# Can we access libraries in android "external" folder

Tags: android

The android source code has an "external" folder where there are many libraries such as jmonkeyengine. I am wondering if I can access those libraries? There are two scenarios that I am interested in:

- If I am just developing an app for the app store, could I somehow use those library (i.e., not including those library in my apk and let my app access them directly from the android system somehow). My initial experiment seems to suggest a "No", I basically compile an apk that use jmonkeyengine library - but I exclude the library from the apk. The app would crash immediately when launched because my activity refereed to a jmonkey class.
- If I am developing an "internal app" for an android device (as in compile the whole android source code with my app in the "app" folder in the source code), will I be able to access these library by default?) I have not try anything here yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after working on it for a while, I think I have the answers:

1. The answer for the first question, from my experience (as oppose to reading some references...), is NO.
2. The answer for the second questions is also NO. By default you will not get access to it. You get access to it by changing the build files instructing android to link your app to the library. At this point this sounds very obvious to me, but at the time I wrote the question that is not very clear